# I updated Windows 10, now "Microsoft Teams" starts each time I log in?

Tags: windows-10, adware, bloatware

Every time I log in to Windows 10, the following ad pops up:

[image: Windows Team Bloatware]

I've done nothing I'm aware of to sign up for teams, and I frankly don't even know what it purports to do.  Yet, its not so easy to get rid of.  How can I?

What the heck installed it?

Comment: That's not an add, it's the start screen of teams. Try to remove it from auto start (https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/remove-windows-10-startup-programs-3615075/%3famp)

Comment: Probably you was chosen by Windows 10 Consumer Experience program to test this software (it is like all this games, Windows 10 is regularly installing in Start menu). As this is Microsoft software, they trust it enough to allow start when computer starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable it from the Task Manager's Startup tab.
[image: Disabling MS Teams at Startup]

Or better yet uninstall both "Microsoft Teams" and "Teams Machine-Wide Installer".

[image: Removing Microsoft Teams]

Comment: Exactly how I wrote it below, but without images. And gets down-voted. I give up this site... honestly..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do the following?

1. Open Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc)
2. Switch to Startup tab.
3. Find Microsoft Teams and disable it.

Hope that helps. Otherwise you can just try to uninstall it:

1. Right click on the start menu button
2. Choose "Apps and functions"
3. Locate Microsoft Teams and uninstall it.